# Keep gearman worker in listening mode after loading file content

Tags: python, gearman

I want to keep some file content loaded in memory so that it can be queried in retrived instantly.

In gearman worker, I am loading the file and put it in listening mode. While making request using gearman client, `worker` returns loaded content only once, next time client receives `None`

worker :

```
class GetLexiconFiles(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
        self.loadFiles()
        self.gm_worker.register_task('load_db', self.task_listener_reverse)
        #self.loadFiles()
        #self.gm_worker.work()



    def task_listener_reverse(self, gearman_worker, gearman_job):
        k=float('inf')
        #print "Started loading file"
        self.input_text = self.input_text.split('\n')
        print "Loading completed"
        lexicon = defaultdict(list)
        for i, line in enumerate(self.input_text):
        #print "line is : ", line
            if i >= k: break
            #if i % 100000 == 0: print >>sys.stderr, i
            try:
                if line != '':
                    nl, dbs = line.split(' ', 1)
                    nl = int(nl)
                    dbs = self.str2obj(dbs)
                    lexicon[nl].append(dbs)
                else:
                    pass
            except:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'could not parse line %r' % line
                print traceback.format_exc()
                continue
    return json.dumps(lexicon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GetLexiconFiles().gm_worker.work()
```

client :

```
def check_request_status(job_request):
    if job_request.complete:
        #data = json.loads(job_request.result)
        print "Job %s finished!  Result: %s - %s" % (job_request.job.unique, job_request.state, job_request.result)
    elif job_request.timed_out:
        print "Job %s timed out!"
    elif job_request.state == JOB_UNKNOWN:
        print "Job %s connection failed!"

gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['localhost:4730'])
tasks = [{'task': 'load_lexicon', 'data': 'This is testing sentence'}, {'task': 'load_db', 'data': 'This is db testing'}]

submitted_requests = gm_client.submit_multiple_jobs(tasks, background=False, wait_until_complete=False)

completed_requests = gm_client.wait_until_jobs_completed(submitted_requests)
print completed_requests[1].result
for completed_job_request in completed_requests:
    check_request_status(completed_job_request)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.input_text = self.input_text.split('\n')
```

With this line of code you are converting a string to a list of strings.

Since you save the result back in *self.input_text* the next time that that function gets called *self.input_text* will already be a list and it'll raise an exception.